# Magento, class to switch configurable product image

Tags: image, magento, switch-statement, product, configurable

I trying to use [baobaz](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-reload-color-images-for-configurable-product) class and [magentowiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/change_product_image_on_view_page_to_associated_product_s_image) code to implement magento store and switch image when user select a different product attribute, however with baobaz class i can change image only once and cant back with others products images when the user select different attribute. --eg (i select blue tshirt color attribute and the class will return the result with the photo, then i select red attribute and the class stuck on the first image). With magentowiki nothing happens

```
class Baobaz_Imageswitch_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $prod_id  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('prod_id');
        $color_value  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('color_id');
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id);
        if($color_value) {
            $allProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $product);      
            foreach ($allProducts as $prod) {
                if ($prod->getData('image_storing') && $prod->getColor()==$color_value) { // && $prod->isSaleable() 
                    break;
                }
            }           
            $prod_full=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod->getId());
            Mage::register('product', $prod_full);
        }
        else {
            Mage::register('product', $product);
        }
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Simple Configurable Products](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) extension from Organic Internet has an image switcher which we've used successfully on a couple of projects.  Be aware that it changes how pricing of the configurable products works, but it's an excellent extension.  It's free, open source, and available on Github and [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html).

Comment: It also breaks reindexing on magento 1.7

Comment: The Aligent fork of SCP (https://github.com/aligent/magento-configurable-simple) has fixes for 1.7.  We haven't tried SCP on CE1.8 or EE1.13 though.